# Automatize PHP include

Tags: php, include

i am looking for a way to automatize my php script, it should search for php files in a folder called `SUBPAGES` and include the php files with the Help of a `Dropdown` like my example but without recoding it everytime i add a new file.

It should find the files stored in the `SUBPAGES` folder by itself and include the selected file automatized.

Can any one please help me in solving it.

```
<html>

<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">

<div align="center">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="" height="">
<tr>
<td width="300" height="50" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">

<p align="center">

<form name="form">
<p align="center">
<select name="link" SIZE="1" onChange="window.location.href = document.form.link.options[document.form.link.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="#" style="display:none">Choose</option>
<option value="index.php?id=page1"> Seite1 </option>
<option value="index.php?id=page2"> Seite2 </option>
</select></p>
</form>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="20" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="350">

<?php
error_reporting(0);
switch($_GET['id']) {
default:
include('Subpages/page1.php');
break; case "page2":
include('Subpages/page2.php');
}
?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more easy with jquery and the load function. You only need to read the value of the selected option and load the file that you need

```
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="" height="">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="300" height="50" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">

                            <p align="center">

                            <form name="form">
                                <p align="center">
                                    <select name="link" SIZE="1">
                                    <option value="#" style="display:none">Choose</option>
                                    <option value="page1"> Seite1 </option>
                                    <option value="page2"> Seite2 </option>
                                    </select>
                                </p>
                            </form>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="350" id="result"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        $( "#result" ).load( "Subpages/" + $(this).val() + ".php" );
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way. firstly check the type of security, after include

```
$page = 'Subpages/page'.settype($_GET['id'],'integer').'.php' ;
$defaultpage = 'Subpages/page1.php' ;
if (file_exists($page)) {
        include($page);
}else{
 include($defaultpage);
}
```